# Cannot locate or retrieve uploaded graph-video data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing my first facebook app, My app uploads videos to the app using  GET graph-videos then posts a link to the video on on the users wall.

Below is a code snippet from developers.facebook.com which I am using to upload the video files to Facebook.
My problem is, when the video finishes its upload, no data is returned and Its been an impossible task to track which GET graph query I need to retrieve links to the uploaded videos which are need for the second part of the application.

```
$post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/343226535752652/videos?"
. "title=" . $video_title. "&description=" . $video_desc 
. "&". $access_token;

$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment);
```

I've tried countless calls to the graph and changing the GET graph parameters whilst monitoring the differences using the Graph Explorer but I've had no luck.

Any suggestions or ideas on were all my video uploads are hiding or bugs in my code would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please actually post your code. Looks like you're getting two methods (i.e. raw posting to graph, plus posting via SDK) muddled up.

Comment: _“My problem is, when the video finishes its upload, no data is returned”_ – once you finished your upload, the video get’s processed server-side by Facebook, and that takes some time. Therefore information about an uploaded video are not avialable via the Graph API _immediately_ – try checking back after some time.